# How many ways to form a committee?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose there is a group of 7 Republicans, 6 Democrats, and 4 Independents. How many ways are there to form a committee with 6 members, if it must have at least 4 Republicans?

So I took C(7,4) * C(13,2) = 2730 for a final result. Is this correct?

Comment: Try breaking this down into the cases where you get 4 Republicans, 5 Republicans, and 6 Republicans; and then add the number of possibilities for these 3 cases.  I think you'll see that your answer is too large.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is
$$C(7,4) * C(10,2)+C(7,5) * C(10,1)+C(7,6) * C(10,0)$$

Comment: @bof thank you, you are completely right

Answer (score 0):

There is a secret trick to testing your reasoning in problems like this. The problem you're given is way too hard, there are thousands of possibilities. Here's the trick:

**Try it with smaller numbers.**

Suppose there is a group of $2$ Republicans and $1$ Democrat. How many ways are there to form a committee with $2$ members, if it must have at least $1$ Republican?

What do you get if you try to solve it the same way you did the original problem? Do you get $C(2,1)*C(2,1)$? Is that the correct answer? If not, can you see what you did wrong?